# Moving and Renaming Files Using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

As it turns out I am now being asked to modify the script so it delivers each respective file into its own folder. All files will reside in one folder on a AS400 and will move to different folders on a separate computer. My question is can I get away with something like:

```
Dim fso,f,strPathBuild

Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("Z:\SOURCE")

For Each file In f.Files

if left(UCase(file.Name),1) = "A" then strPathBuild = Replace(file, "Z:\SOURCE", "Y:\DESTINATION1")

if left(UCase(file.Name),1) = "A" then strPathBuild = Replace(strPathBuild,"A","ACKNOWLEDGE")

if left(UCase(file.Name),1) = "S" then strPathBuild = Replace(file, "Z:\SOURCE", "Y:\DESTINATION2")

if left(UCase(file.Name),1) = "S" then strPathBuild = Replace(strPathBuild,"S","SHIPMENT")

fso.MoveFile file, strPathBuild

Next

Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

I apologize but it seems the PM likes to refrain from giving me all the requirements at once.

Comment: Hello again. Just run this script on my system and don't get any errors. Can you update your question with more on the "continued errors". Taa

Comment: Jon, I just noticed a typo. The script works!

Comment: Was scratching my head a bit!

Comment: This PM is going to drive me crazy! How can I write the script so it only changes the file name when the first character is "A" and just moves other files where the first character is something other than "A"? Do I just do "IF THEN"?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, just edit this one if you need to revise something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In answer to your commented question:

```
Dim fso,f,strPathBuild

Set fso=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder("Z:\SOURCE")

For Each file In f.Files

strPathBuild = Replace(file, "Z:\SOURCE", "Y:\DESTINATION")

if left(UCase(file.Name),1) = "A" then strPathBuild = Replace(strPathBuild,"ACK","ACKNOWLEDGE")

fso.MoveFile file, strPathBuild

Next

Set f = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Also, as Alex K says, you want to start watching out for case sensitivity on your file names. (That's why I included the UCase function)

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I appreciate your patience in helping a novice like myself.

Answer (score 0):

The case of the path in the enumeration probably does not match the `Replace` search criteria.

Case insensitive replace (with start at char 1, replace 1 time);

`strPathBuild = Replace(file, "Z:\SOURCE", "Y:\DESTINATION", 1, 1, vbTextCompare)`

Comment: Would you expect errors from that though? - it just wouldn't move the files.