# Moving files from root directory in AS400

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange

I have a script which moves and renames files from an AS400 directory to a Windows directory on a separate server.  The successful process moves data from a folder created in a library on the AS400. For technical reasons the AS400 developer moved the source data to the root on the AS400.

Now that I have modified the script to point to the different source I get an error "Invalid procedure call or argument".  My question is can we move data from the AS400 root or does it have to reside within a library? I can still move files from within the library but not from the root.  Any advice?  Thanks!

Comment: I think there is a bunch of terminology problems here. Is this files on the IFS or is this in a library? IIRC, you can't move an object to the "root", it must reside in a library. Can you provide a bit more information like where the file was, where it got moved to and how you are pulling this information?

Comment: To expand on Mike Wills's comment: We need to be very careful about terminology. On the AS/400, a folder is not the same as a directory (well, a folder is a special kind of directory; most directories are not folders). If possible, more information would help greatly. Which of the following, if any, rings a bell: QSYS, QDLS, IFS? Are you able to give any specific names of directories or libraries you have used?

Comment: Wence, is this a continuation of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268069)?  If so, it looks like the source directory is an IFS dir that is being shared out as a Windows file share.  Can you post the new VBScript code?

Comment: @dmc it is a continuation and the script works great when I am reading from QDLS but the source has been changed to an IFS directory. The AS400 developer changed security settings which allowed for the script to move the text files from the AS400 directory and place them on a separate windows server. My problem now is that I have to overwrite when files exist otherwise just move the files.  Crash course in VBScripting was not part of the project but now I have some knowledge of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your comment (and your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268069/)) correctly, you need to be able to move a file with the ability to overwrite.  One way to do that is by copying and deleting.  `CopyFile` will overwrite a file by default.

```
fso.CopyFile strFromFile, strToPath
fso.DeleteFile strFromFile
```

See the following MSDN pages for [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`DeleteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thx0f315(v=vs.85).aspx) for additional details.

Answer (score 0):

If the root is "/" then this is not a library and you are having a flat file similar to what it will be on the Windows box.  You will most likely not be able to use your existing toolkits for this, but perhaps CPYSTRF or similar?  Can you just ftp it in from the Windows box?